# Password validation program cpp

Tags: c++, goto

I am creating a password validation program and I want the password to contain the following:

```
* Password must be between 8 to 15 characters long...
* Password must contain at least one digit
* Password must contain at least one Uppercase
* Password must contain at least one number
* Password must contain at least one lowercase
* Password must contain at least one symbol
```

And if the user enters an invalid password, the program should ask the user to re-enter password. But I'm stuck on how to make the user re-enter the password if its wrong. I tried using 'goto' but its not working...

```
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

using namespace std;

bool verify_password();

int main() {
    
    char userName;
    char password[15];

    
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\tEnter User Name: ";
    cin >> userName;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    
    
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\tEnter Password: ";
    cin >> password;

    
    bool result = verify_password();
    if (result) cout<<"Verified password\n";
    else {
        cout<<"Invalid password\n";
        cout<<result;
    }
    
        
    system("pause>0");
}

bool verify_password(){
    
    int lenght = strlen(password);
    if (lenght < 8 || lenght > 15) return false;
    
    bool has_upper = false;
    bool has_lower = false;
    bool has_symbol = false;
    bool has_digit = false;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++){
        
        if(isupper(password[i])) has_upper = true;
        if(islower(password[i])) has_lower = true;
        if(isdigit(password[i])) has_digit = true;
        if(ispunct(password[i])) has_symbol = true;
    }

    if(!(has_upper && has_lower && has_digit && has_symbol)) return false;
    
    
}
```

Comment: `goto checkPassword;` -- Don't do this.  You a proper looping construct, such as `do-while`.  As soon as you use `goto`, you have driven away a lot of people willing to help -- no one wants to detangle spaghetti code.

Comment: `cin >> password;` - And if the person enters a password greater than 14 characters, your program has a buffer overflow.  You should be using `std::string`, not a char array.

Comment: `cin >> userName;` -- The `userName` is a single `char`.  This also should be `std::string`.

Comment: By the way, for validating password the most suitable concept to use would be regular expressions.

Comment: Other obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/292

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of issues with this code, but the things you should change to start:

1. Make your verify password function ONLY verify the password. It is currently doing more than that.
2. Get user input in the main() function. Once you get the password here, you can do something like:

```cpp
int trys = 0;
while (trys < 3) {
    cout << "Enter Password: ";
    cin >> password;
    if (verify_password(password)) {
        cout << "valid!" << endl;
        break;
    }

    cout << "invalid..." << endl;
    ++trys;
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is some issue preventing me from formatting code... maybe someone can try and edit it?

Comment: Side note: The villain was the list. You need to put something between the list and the code in order for the renderer to recognize and format indented code

Comment: It's still not working @MichaelICE

Comment: The above code was more of a suggestion. You're going to have to modify your program a lot for it to work.  As frustrated as you must be now, the best advice I can give you is to go back to the books, and learn c++ from the beginning, perhaps even python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to execute the function again. Replace the following:

```
if(!(has_upper && has_lower && has_digit && has_symbol)){ 
       goto checkPassword;
       return false;}
```

With recursion, such as:

```
if(!(has_upper && has_lower && has_digit && has_symbol))
       return verify_password();
```

Comment: Using recursion is not how this problem should be solved.  If someone writes a script that enters a bad password a thousand times, the function stack may become exhausted.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: I understand, @PaulMcKenzie. I will look into a method to mitigate this.

Comment: Have you made certain the problem is the re-execution of this function and not another part of your code?

Comment: The program still ends when I replaced it

Comment: Yes @Anonymous_Codesman

Comment: I have identified the problem as the following line of code:
`if (lenght < 8 || lenght > 15) return false;`
The program returns false before it can reach the final return statements.

Comment: The simplest solution to mitigate exhaustion due to recursion is to use a while loop in the `main()` function that executes the `verify_password()` function if it is false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246498/discussion-between-ratty-jhay-and-anonymous-codesman).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using `goto` statements is not a good practice for coding, it's much clearer to use other kind of loops like `while` and `for`.

For your problem here I would suggest to re-organize the code in smaller functions:

```
requestUsername() //Call it to ask user for the username
requestPassword() //Call it to ask user for password
verifyPassword()  //Call it to verify the provided password
```

Then, you could structure your main like this:

```
username = requestUsername();
password = requestPassword();
while(!verifyPassword(password)) //Invalid password
{
  password = requestPassword();
}
```

Or:

```
username = requestUsername();
do
{
  password = requestPassword();
}while(!verifyPassword(password)) //Invalid password
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What return type should I give the functions because its not working @coses

Comment: @RattyJhay in this case you would want the request functions to return a string (`char*` in C), and the verify to return a `bool`. I would suggest to look up some documentation on strings and pointers if you are not familiar with those.